# Make a Chromecast Mini Controller sticky

Tags: android, android-studio, video, chromecast

We have created a video app for Android and we have also connected it with the Chromecast library. [We created a Mini Controller in the notification bar and lock screen using this exact code here.](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#add_media_controls_to_notification_and_lock_screen)

Problem: the Mini Controller can be dismissed as a regular notification instead staying *sticky*, like the Mini Controller in the YouTube app.

I have found how to make a *sticky* regular notification, but not how to alter the one given in the Chromecast Docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using [deprecated SDK version (v2?)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastApi) in which the notification is not sticky. If you do casting using the new [Cast SDK (Cast Application Framework (CAF))](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_migrate_sender), the notification will be sticky automatically.